# How to inject module and make it accesible to entrie angular app

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I have a module **(app.config)** that I would like to inject my entire app.

**The module needs to be accessible within all other modules injected into the app**

For example, my app looks like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
    'app.config',
    'module#1',
    'module#2',
    'module#3',
    'module#4'    
])
.config...
```

/////////////////////////////////

**Here's app.config**

```
angular.module('app.config', []).
    constant('NAME1', 'Name1').
    constant('NAME2', 'Name2'); 
////////////////////
```

I want 'app.config' injected in such a way that it can be accessed inside all modules (module#1','module#2',....) as well.

**Here's my problem:**

```
angular.module('module#1', []).
    service('serviceOne', serviceOne);

function ServiceOne($http) {

    var service = {
        getMyProfile: function(){return $http.get('api/' + NAME1);}
    };

    return service;
}
```

Problem -> **NAME1 is undefined.** But I thought I injected it to the entire app???

**I don't want to individually inject app.config to each module.** Any other solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to inject the constants in to the controller as well.

```
function ServiceOne($http, NAME1) {

   var service = {...
   ...

 }
```

here is a good [explanation](https://gist.github.com/demisx/9605099)

Answer (score 0):

`NAME1` is the key by which Angular knows to inject the constant, but you never injected it!  Also, you need to add a dependency on the module in which you set the constants (in this case, `'app.config'`) in `'Module1'`.  Also, when I'm creating services, I just add the methods to `this` which is a reference to the service itself, so I don't need to bother with creating an object for the service and returning it as you were doing in your example.  Finally, it's best practice to use the [inline array annotation for dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#inline-array-annotation) as shown in my example below.  Try this out:

```
var mod1 = angular.module('Module1', ['app.config']);

mod1.service('ServiceOne', ['$http', 'NAME1', serviceOne]);

function ServiceOne($http, NAME1) {

  this.getMyProfile = function() {
    return $http.get('api/' + NAME1);
  };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a config object

app.config

```
module.exports = {
    NAME1: 'Name1',
    NAME2: 'Name2'
}
```

and then

```
var config = require('../config');

angular.module('module#1', []).
    service('serviceOne', serviceOne);

function ServiceOne($http) {

    var service = {
        getMyProfile: function(){return $http.get('api/' + config.NAME1);}
    };

    return service;
}
```