# How to inject a module and make it accesible to all modules and submodules of app (getting unknown provider error)

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

Please note this is **not** a duplicate of:[How to inject module and make it accesible to entrie angular app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220201/how-to-inject-module-and-make-it-accesible-to-entrie-angular-app)

I have a module **(`app.config`)** that I would like to inject into my entire app.

**The module needs to be accessible within all other modules and submodules(modules inside modules) injected into `myApp`**

For example, my app looks like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
    'app.config',
    'module#1',
    'module#2',
    'module#3',
    'module#4'    
])
.config...
```

/////////////////////////////////

**Here's `app.config`**

```
angular.module('app.config', []).
    constant('NAME1', 'Name1').
    constant('NAME2', 'Name2'); 
////////////////////
```

I want `'app.config'` injected in such a way that it should be accesible in `module#500` which is not directly a dependecy of `'myApp'`, but a dependecy of `module#1` - which, in turn, is a dependecy of `myApp`.

`module#1` is defined as such (as shown,`module#500` is a dependecy of `module#1`):

```
 angular.module('module#1', [
        'module#500',
        'module#501',
        'module#502',
        ...    
    ]);
```

**Here's my problem:**

```
angular.module('module#500', []).
    service('serviceOne', serviceOne);

function ServiceOne($http, NAME1) {

    var service = {
        getMyProfile: function(){return $http.get('api/' + NAME1);}
    };

    return service;
}
```

Problem - I get an error-> **`Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: NAME1Provider <-NAME1 <- serviceOne`** But I thought I injected it to the entire app???

**I don't want to add `module#500` directly as dependency to `'myApp'`** I wan't to leave `module#500` as a dependecy of `module#1`. And I want to leave `module#1` as a dependency of `myApp`

**I don't want to individually inject `app.config` to each and every module either.** Any other solutions?

Comment: You might be getting unable to resolve dependency error. Not NAME is undefined...

Comment: sorry @Vishwanath - I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. "Not Name is undefined"?

Comment: are you getting error "Name is undefined"?

Comment: Exact error is: `Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: NAME1Provider <-NAME1 <- serviceOne`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to make `myApp` dependent on `app.config` (though it would be the right thing to do because its submodules ***depend*** on it), you can load config module with manual bootstrapping

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp', 'app.config']);
```

instead of `ng-app="myApp"`.

Comment: We were actually using deferredBootstrap and "pretty much the same" concept worked for us. So I'll give you a check anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want to individually inject app.config to each and every
>   module either. Any other solutions?

I don't know what solution you could be expecting? With this line: `angular.module('module#500', []).` how is module#500 going to know about anything else, it has nothing given to it. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here.

edit, as I've just read your post and comments from yesterday: I think you're not understanding dependency-injection properly. It only goes one way, module#1 has access to module#500, but module#500 doesn't have access to module#1. It has to be that way: How could you unit-test module#500 if it has some behavior that depends on module#1, which is not mentioned anywhere in its code?

I'm *guessing* your project doesn't really call for so many modules, if they all depend on the same config variables. Those factories and services that depend on the config variables should be in the same module with it. That is proper compartmentalization and will make your life easier in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to inject `NAME1` in your `ServiceOne` service.

eg: `function ServiceOne($http, NAME1)`

Comment: sorry, I now added NAME1 to serviceOne. That is not the problem. It was just a typo. Thanks alot for pointing it out! If possible, pls remove this answer so as not to confuse. You may add it as a comment if you like. Thanks